# Looking at a list of numbers and getting that number from another file>

Tags: python, list, memory, append

I don't really know how to word the question, but I have this file with a number and a decimal next to it, like so(the file name is num.txt):

```
33    0.239
78    0.298
85    1.993
96    0.985
107    1.323
108    1.000
```

I have this string of numbers that I want to find the certain numbers from the file, take the decimal numbers, and append it to a list:

```
['78','85','108']
```

Here is my code so far:

```
chosen_number = ['78','85','108']
memory_list = []
for line in open(path/to/num.txt):
    checker = line[0:2]
    if not checker in chosen_number: continue
    dec = line.split()[-1]
    memory_list.append(float(dec))
```

The error they give to me is that it is not in a list and they only account for the 3 digit numbers. I don't really understand why this is happening and would like some tips to know how to fix it. Thanks.

As for the error, there is no actual error. The only problem is that they ignore the two digit numbers and only get the three digit numbers. I want them to get both the 2 and 3 digit numbers. For example, the script would pass 78 and 85, going to the line with '108'.

Comment: All numbers in your file are decimal, but those on the left are integer, and those on the right, floating-point. Also, please include the whole error message in your question.

Comment: ``checker`` seems to be undefined. Also: if you get an error please add the complete traceback to your question.

Comment: @mpf82 checker has been identified and for error, there is no error but the script just ignores the 3 digit numbers and only looks at the 2 digit ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your `checker` is undefined. The below code works.

N.B. I have used `startswith` because, the number might appear elsewhere in the line.

```
chosen_number = ['78','85','108']
memory_list = []

with open('path/to/num.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(line.startswith(i) for i in chosen_number):
            memory_list.append(float(line.split()[1]))

print(memory_list)
```

Output:

```
[0.298, 1.993, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would should work:

```
chosen_number = ['78','85','108']
memory_list = []

with open('num.txt') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        v1, v2 = line.split()

        if v1 in chosen_number:
            memory_list.append(float(v2))

print memory_list
```

Giving you:

```
[0.298, 1.993, 1.0]
```

Also, it is better to use a `with` statement when dealing with files so that the file is automatically closed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
chosen_number = ['78 ', '85 ', '108 ']
memory_list = []

for line in open("num.txt"):
    for num in chosen_number:
        if num in line:
            dec = line.split()[-1]
            memory_list.append(float(dec))
```

In `chosen number`, I declared numbers with a space after: `'85 '`. Otherwise  when `0.985` is found, the if condition would be true, as they're used as string. I hope, I'm clear enough.